# Prediction model for Time Series forecasting (1 target, multiple controllable variables)

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, recurrent-neural-network, forecasting

I have a time series forecasting problem that has one target variable, and multiple independent variable. Think of temperature as the target variable, with amount of fuel, time of heating etc as the independent (controllable) variables. Suppose I have a database of temperature rising with a stream of fuel, heating time, oxygen flow etc etc. I now want to predict some n steps into the future, how my temperature graph will look like, based on GIVEN values of fuel and other parameters for those n steps. Suppose I'll say I want to maintain fuel flow rate at m kg/m3 etc for the next 5 hours. How should I model this time series problem? Any pointers will be really helpful!

I used LSTMs to code this, but the prediction model is not accurate at all.

https://github.com/RiddhimanRaut/Deep-Learning-based-CPR-estimation/blob/main/CPR_prediction_multivariate_LSTM_tobetrialled_1.ipynb

Also, is this a multivariate case? I am not trying to predict future values of other parameters, just one. I am really confused.

Comment: Temperature and the other features are input channels. Temperature for future timesteps is the output. That is no problem. That's it, that's what you can train the network on.

Comment: You might want to use the attention mechanism and/or convolutional networks. They are easier to train than LSTM.